# Происхождение слова "щепетильный"

Tags: этимология

"Щепетильный" - так говорят о человеке, внимательном и даже придирчивом к мелочам. например, *"Он очень щепетилен в вопросах чести"*.
Но интересно было бы узнать происхождение этого слова. От какого слова оно может происходить? На ум сразу приходить слово "щепоть", но оно по смыслу никак не вяжется. И русский ли корень у этого слова?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Щепоть, действительно,другой смысл, а вот щепа. щепка, как совершенно справедливо отметил Тагир, исходное слово - "мелкая часть". Ему однокоренные, как ни странно,отщепенец и чепуха(щеп/чеп)

Было ещё такое старое прилагательное ЩЕПНОЙ, -ая, -ое. 1.От "щепа". 2. Относящийся к мелким токарным и резным деревянным изделиям, а также к изделиям из лучины (устар.). Щепной товар. Щепной двор (место изготовления и продажи таких изделий).

У прилагательного щепетильный  было 3 значения:

1.галантерейный и парфюмерный;

2.изысканный, модный в одежде, застегнутый на все пуговицы, церемонный;

3.неодобр.  мелочной, занятый только внешним, мелочами, пустяками.

Смысл этого слова в эпоху Пушкина и в наше время не совпадает.

- Все, чем для прихоти обильной
  Торгует Лондон щепетильный (А. Пушкин). Здесь - "модный"

В книге-исповеди, последнем произведении Константина Симонова “Глазами человека моего поколения” (написана в 1979 г., издана в 1990 г.), имеются такие слова о деде писателя: дед с княжеским титулом всю жизнь служил и был щепетильный. Какое значение имеет это слово? Скорее всего, придирчиво-педантичный.

Первоначальное значение щепетильный -“очень следящий за своей одеждой” на базе значения глагола щепетить “модничать, наряжаться, щеголять”. Такое значение развилось на основе значения “мелочи галантерейного характера”.Щепетильник - продавец галантерейных мелочей.

В русской речи развилось еще одно значение слова щепетильный -“требующий осторожного и тактичного отношения, деликатный” (щепетильная ситуация, щепетильный вопрос).
Эти значения закрепились в современном русском языке и далеки от былого “галантерейного” значения пушкинской поры. Писатели и журналисты рядом со словом щепетильный в современном значении часто ставят близкие по смыслу слова тонкий, деликатный и др.

Answer (score 3):

Слова "щепетильный и щепоть" – это, действительно, очень дальние родственники, и  у каждого слова  своя история.

ЩЕПЕТИЛЬНЫЙ

Существует интересная  русская фамилия Щапов. Оказывается, представители этой фамилии любили «щапить» – щеголять напоказ, франтить, модничать, также «щепетить».    Любимые ими  галантерейные товары – пуговицы, тесемочки, духи, помада  - раньше  назывались щепетильными, но потом это слово устарело.  Так, в  1765 году вышла комедия Лукина  «Щепетильник», где говорилось: «Пожалуй, брось ты это  варварское имя и называйся галантерейщиком».

Слово "щепет" происходит от и.-е. корня skep – резать, рубить, отделять, но при чем тут щегольство? Ответ получается неоднозначный. С одной стороны, это сходство со словом «щепа» в значении "мелкая отколотая часть  дерева". Без сомнения, щеголи  были очень неравнодушны к  галантерейным мелочам. С другой стороны,  они чем-то сами походили на «щепы», то есть старались отделиться/выделиться из толпы своим щегольством.

Итак, щепетильный - это очень внимательный к мелочам, к деталям. Вероятно, франты пушкинского времени  изящество в своей внешности и одежде мелочами не считали, поэтому и устарело "варварское" слово. Его современное значение  - строго, до мелочей принципиальный. Вот и нам со слишком щепетильными людьми общаться не очень комфортно, так как такая щепетильность, в полном соответствии с этимологией слова,  легко превращается в мелочность.

ЩЕПОТЬ

Это исконное слово, производное от  "щипать", первоначально – то, с помощью чего можно это сделать, ср. щипти – пальцы. Но  и в глаголе «щипать» тот же и.-е корень skip, что и в слове "щепетильный", который означает "разобщать, разъединять, отделять".

Answer (score 1):

Происходит от щепети́ть «наряжаться, модничать», щепети́льник «галантерейщик, мелочной торговец», щепети́льный; диал. ще́петкой «плотный, крепкий, прочный», арханг., щепетли́вый «щегольской», щепети́нье «галантерейные товары». Первонач., по-видимому, ще́пет «галантерея» от щепа́ в знач. «мелочь».